# Media playback in Qt application only possible when executing as root

Tags: linux, qt, permissions, environment-variables

I'm not entirely sure whether my issue is related to shared library access or if it is Qt-specific, but here goes:

In short, I have a Qt5.5 application that includes a video and audio player, based on QtMultimedia. When I run the application as root, the video plays; otherwise, it stays stuck in the *Loading* status. Absolutely no error is given.

Slightly longer story: I am unable to use Qt5.2 as provided in the official Ubuntu 14.04 repos, because my application uses both the QtWebKit and QtMultimedia modules; unfortunately, these modules are built against gstreamer 0.1 and 1.0 respectively, and thus do not play nicely together.

So, I have installed Qt5.5 from [this repository](https://launchpad.net/~beineri/+archive/ubuntu/opt-qt551-trusty), which installs to `/opt/qt55`. Despite setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH as indicated, I run into the problem described above. But when running the application as root, everything works without a hitch.

This is the output of `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` :

```
/opt/qt55/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/opt/qt55/lib
```

For what it's worth, I've only just realized that it worked when run as root, so I tried compiling Qt5.5 from source on another, clean, machine (with neither Qt5.2 nor 5.5 from the repos), and it works fine there. So I assume there is either a problem with the Qt5.5 build (which seems unlikely) or with my environment.

**Edit** : If it's any help, media plays when executing the application with `sudo ./app` or after `sudo -s`, but *not* after `sudo -i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after comparing the outputs of `printenv`, `sudo printenv` and `sudo -i printenv`, I identified the culprit :

`QT_NO_GLIB=1`

Unsetting it solves the problem.